# Is there a G-test equivalent for continuous variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, likelihood-ratio, kullback-leibler

The [G-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test#Relation_to_Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) is similar to the chi-square test for goodness of fit. It is proportional to the [kl-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence).

I am wondering if there is a similar test that is applicable to continuous variables. Since there is a [continuous version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition) of kl-divergence, so I imagine there could be something of this sort.

I'm also guessing the [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) wouldn't be the answer, since it focuses on goodness of fit based on max distance of the CDF, while kl-divergence is a metric that relies an averaging.

Comment: G-test is just a likelihood ratio test ...

Comment: I would add that the G-test is a (generalized) likelihood ratio test (the alternative is rather big here, including all but the single prob. vector being used as the null parameter).

Comment: Almost all of our tests for complex alternatives are GLRT :)

Answer (score 3):

The G-test has become a favorite of mine for proportion testing. ;)

The way it works is by fitting a (multinomial) logistic regression model with a factor variable as a predictor, plus an intercept. Then it fits an intercept-only model. Finally, it performs a likelihood ratio test of the factor variable by comparing the two models. (I have verified this with simulations in R, and I would encourage skeptical readers to do the same.)

If you want to do something similar but for a continuous predictor, fit a model with that predictor (and intercept), fit a model with just the intercept, and perform a likelihood ratio test.

Comment: Hey, thanks. (1) I think you have some type in the last sentence, could you please revise? (2) any chance to share your R code? (I'm curious). (3) Any chance for an example on how to do this for a continuous variable? (R code is good :) )